# cannot read property getExif of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, exif

if anyone could help with this that would be great. I'm using react native and trying to read the exif data specifically the date of a image.

i'm using the react-native-exif npm module but i'm getting "Cannot read property 'getExif' of undefined"

Here is my code (index.js):

```
Exif.getExif = function (uri) { 
    const path = uri.replace('file://', '');
    console.log(path);
    return NativeModules.ReactNativeExif.getExif(path).then(result => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return unifyAndroid(result);
        }
        return unifyIOS(result);
    });
};
```

console.log(path) 
returns img.jpg

img.jpg is in the same directory as index.js

Many thanks 
Andy

Comment: Which line is the error on, `return NativeModules.ReactNativeExif.getExif(path)` or somewhere else where you call `Exif.getExif`?

Comment: it errors on this line: return NativeModules.ReactNativeExif.getExif(path)

Comment: Seems as though it wasn't imported properly.